# How to force PageView to refresh page on change?

Tags: flutter, flutter-pageview

I have implemented PageView and I want in one scenario to refresh page when I change to this page.

How to achieve this?

My pages are another classes than my PageView class.

Here is my code

```
child: PageView(
                        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(
                            parent: BouncingScrollPhysics()),
                        onPageChanged: (page) {
                          setState(() {
                            currentIndex = page;
                          });
                        },
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        controller: pageController,
                        children: widget.noAccount == null
                            ? [
                                const NoConnectionWidgetHandler(
                                    child: PartyPage()),
                                const NoConnectionWidgetHandler(
                                    child: ClubsPage()),
                                const QrCamera(),
                                const NoConnectionWidgetHandler(
                                    child: FriendsPage()),
                                const NoConnectionWidgetHandler(
                                    child: ProfilePage()),
                              ]
```

```
void changePage(int page, BuildContext context) async {
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    if (page == 2) {
      Provider.of<QrProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .changeCameraVisibility(true);
    } else if (Provider.of<QrProvider>(context, listen: false).isQrCameraOn) {
      Provider.of<QrProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .changeCameraVisibility(false);
    }
    print('previous $currentIndex');
    if (currentIndex == 0) {
      print('wysyłam statystyki o kliknietych eventach');
      var stats = await MySecureStorage().readData('stats_event');
      print('arr: $stats');
      if (stats != null) {
        // send data
      }
      await MySecureStorage().deleteData('stats_event');
    }
    else if (currentIndex == 1) {
      print('wysyłam statystyki o kliknietych partyspotach');
      var stats = await MySecureStorage().readData('stats_partyspots');
      print('arr: $stats');
      if (stats != null) {
        // send data
      }
      await MySecureStorage().deleteData('stats_partyspots');
    }
    if (currentIndex + 1 == page || currentIndex - 1 == page) {
      currentIndex = page;
      pageController.animateToPage(page,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.ease);
    } else {
      currentIndex = page;
      pageController.jumpToPage(page);
    }
    print('current $currentIndex');
  }
```

Here is my part of PartyPage class, its stateful widget, and here is part I want to refresh:

```
child: Consumer<ControllerProvider>(
                      builder: (context, shower, child) {
                        return FutureBuilder<List>(
                          future: _loadingList,
                          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                            print(snapshot.connectionState);
                            if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.length >= 1) {
                              return LoadingIfNotSatisfied(
                                rebuildIfChanged: Provider.of<MainProvider>(
                                  context,
                                  listen: false,
                                ).isConnectedToInternet,
                                isSatisfied: snapshot.data.isNotEmpty,
                                child: LazyLoadScrollView(
                                  isLoading: isListReloading,
                                  onEndOfPage: () {
                                    //TODO uncomment after pagination on events is fixed
                                    pageNumber += 1;
                                    setState(() {
                                      _loadingList = listLoader(pageNumber, true);
                                    });
                                  },
                                  scrollOffset: (size.height * 3).toInt(),
                                  child: isListLoading
                                    ? Center(
                                      child: SpinKitSquareCircle(
                                        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                          return DecoratedBox(
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                              gradient: const LinearGradient(
                                                begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                                end: Alignment.topRight,
                                                colors: [
                                                  Color(0xffff7a00),
                                                  Color(0xffff00d6)
                                                ],
                                              )),
                                          );
                                        },
                                    ))
                                    : ListViewBuilder(
                                        dataList:
                                          //TODO remove sublist
                                          (snapshot.data as List),
                                        isParty: true,
                                        scrollController: scrollController,
                                        onClick: (details) async {
                                          //TODO wysyłać do backendu informację o tym, że ten klub został odwiedzony - kwestia statystyk - konkretnie odwiedzin danego klubu
                                          print ('details: $details');
                                          var stats = await storage.readData('stats_event');
                                          if (stats == null) {
                                            array.clear();
                                          }
                                          if (!array.contains(details['id'])) {
                                            array.add(details['id']);
                                          }

                                          storage.writeData('stats_event', array.toString());
                                          print(array);
                                          Provider.of<ControllerProvider>(context, listen: false)
                                            .changeFollowOnList(changeFollow);
                                          Provider.of<ControllerProvider>(context, listen: false)
                                            .loadPartyMap(details);
                                          //TODO fix 30 minutes/ reatach controller..
                                          if (shower.controller != null) {
                                            Provider.of<ControllerProvider>(context, listen: false)
                                              .moveMap(LatLng(
                                                  double.parse(details['lat']) +
                                                      0.004,
                                                  double.parse(details['lng'])));
                                            Provider.of<ControllerProvider>(context, listen: false)
                                              .loadMarker(
                                            Marker(
                                              markerId: const MarkerId('1'),
                                              position: LatLng(
                                                double.parse(details['lat']),
                                                double.parse(details['lng']),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        }

                                        Provider.of<ControllerProvider>(context, listen: false).show();
                                      },
                                      refresher: () async {
                                        requestedList = [];
                                        pageNumber = 1;
                                        final loader = listLoader(1, true);
                                        setState(() {
                                          _loadingList = loader;
                                        });
                                        await loader!.whenComplete(() {});
                                      },
                                      size: size),
                                ),
                              );
                            } else if (snapshot.hasData &&
                              snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                return Center(
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      horizontal: size.width * 0.05),
                                    child: Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        AutoSizeText(
                                          local.searchNotFoundEvents,
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                                        ),
                                        Theme(
                                          data: ThemeData(),
                                          child: TextButton(
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              showFilter();
                                            },
                                            child: AutoSizeText(
                                                local.backToFilter,
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25)
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  )
                                );
                              } else {
                                return Center(
                                  child: SpinKitSquareCircle(
                                    duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                      return DecoratedBox(
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                          gradient: const LinearGradient(
                                            begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                            end: Alignment.topRight,
                                            colors: [
                                              Color(0xffff7a00),
                                              Color(0xffff00d6)
                                            ],
                                          )),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ));
                                }
                          },
                        );
                      }),
```

I know this code a little bit messy, but I am junior developer and it is not my code, I am trying to clean it step by step and it's a lot of work with this in this project

Comment: What are you trying to refresh? You can try with passing function.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I want to refresh page. To make it init again or something like this.

Comment: Is there any method which is called everytime when page is opened where I can force refresh?

Comment: PageView doesn't preserving state by default. It recalls `initState`  on page changes, can you provide sample code-snippet that will reproduce the same error?

Comment: I edited my question, there is my code for PageView and changing page

Comment: In my case initState is called once, on first launch, then is not called again